# Cursor within transaction behaves differently between go and psql

Tags: postgresql, go, string-interpolation, database-cursor

I have a problem. For some reason, that is completely beyond me, the cursor I've created behaves differently when I run it in `psql` (where it works), as opposed to when I run it through my `go` code.

I take in a slice of names and pass them as a `pq.Array` to the transaction execute function call. From what I've read, this should do the trick for passing multiple values of arbitrary count to a query. But apparently not.. I don't know if this is happening because it is within a cursor in a transaction, that is the only thing I can think of anymore.

The idea is to query for all `id`'s of `tenants` whose names do **NOT** appear in this list, hence using the `<>` operator. These names are unique in the database.

When I run it through the `go` code, I end up getting all the `id`'s, not just the ones that do not appear in the list.

I've included the function here, the transaction is started in a calling function and passed to this one. Do tell if need to include something else for further clarification!

Am I missing something?

```golang
func DeleteTenants(orphanTenants []string, tx *sql.Tx) error {
    query := `
    DECLARE tenants_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id FROM tenants
    WHERE name <> ALL(ARRAY[$1])
    FOR UPDATE
    `
    if _, err := tx.Exec(query, pq.Array(orphanTenants)); err != nil {
        log.Println("DeleteTenants: Error creating Tenant cursor")
        return err
    }
    defer tx.Exec("CLOSE tenants_cursor")
    for {
        id := -1
        if err := tx.QueryRow("FETCH NEXT FROM tenants_cursor").Scan(&id); err != nil {
            if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
                log.Println("No rows found in tenants_cursor")
                break
            }
            log.Println("DeleteTenants: Error when fetching next row from Tenant cursor")
            return err
        }
        log.Println("Tenant ID to be deleted:", id)
        if err := deleteTenant(id, tx); err != nil {
            log.Println("DeleteTenants: Error returned from deleteTenant")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind.. figured it out. I don't need to include the `ARRAY` notation within the query when passing `pq.Array` to the query.

This is embarrassing! Answer my own question within minutes.

So the query would be like this:

```golang
query := `
DECLARE tenants_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id FROM tenants
WHERE name <> ALL($1)
FOR UPDATE
`
if _, err := tx.Exec(query, pq.Array(orphanTenants)); err != nil {
    log.Println("DeleteTenants: Error creating Tenant cursor")
    return err
}
defer tx.Exec("CLOSE tenants_cursor")
```

Comment: Not sure what the right thing to do here, first time asking a question on here. I imagine it looks a bit sketchy to just post a question and then answer it almost right away.. Do I delete it?